# Connecting MySQL Database with Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: mysql, database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to do this?

I'm familiar with MySQL when it comes to webapps, but I'm learning how to create google chrome extension, and I'd like to somehow connect to my database from existing web app. I have created a form in the `popup.html` from google's example, and would like to send input values to a script to insert data into MySQL when user submits this data. How would I do that?

Right I'm in developing stage and uploading chrome extension is easily done without uploading to my server. So I'm just wondering how I can connect MySQL database if its not localhost?

Thanks!

Comment: @RonLugge I've seen many google chromes extension applications where they require user to login or some what so they can read data or upload data.

Comment: Without actually looking at the apps in question, I *strongly* suspect my answer below is probably the correct answer for you.

Comment: Google has a good starting place on connecting to a database through a server. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: @andrewliu do you need a locally stored database for the chrome extension?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you don't want to give your chrome extension access to the database.  That's a security *nightmare* of biblical proportions.

What you want to do is create a remote web-service that the extension can talk to, that then handles your database operations.

This can be as a PHP script that you call that returns a quick bit of JSON, or vastly more complex.

Comment: Can you show an example of how I can remote or what I need to do to have my extension talk to? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, while I can recognize that your stated request is NOT what you want to do (it's wrong from a security standpoint, and I came on it through the mysql tag), I don't write google extensions.  I could help you write the .php file (if your remote server is PHP based, it could be rails or any other language), but I can't help you with actually getting from google chrome to the server.

Comment: @RonLugge, Not a security nightmare. In fact that's the whole point of MySQL allowing MySQL users to have different limited user rights.